# Given a special Hilbert space $U_0$, is there a proper superspace $V$ such that the inclusion $\iota:U_0\to V$ is Hilbert-Schmidt?

Tags: functional-analysis, operator-theory, hilbert-spaces, inner-products

Let

- $U$ be a Hilbert space
- $Q\in\mathfrak L(U)$ be nonnegative and symmetric
- $U_0:=Q^{1/2}U$ be equipped with $$\langle u,v\rangle_{U_0}:=\langle Q^{-1/2}u,Q^{-1/2}v\rangle_U\;\;\;\text{for }u,v\in U_0$$
- $V$ be a Hilbert space and $\iota\in\operatorname{HS}(U_0,V)$ be an embedding
- $C:=\iota\iota^\ast$

> Let $$V_0:=C^{1/2}V\tag 1$$ be equipped with $$\langle u,v\rangle_{V_0}:=\langle C^{-1/2}u,C^{-1/2}v\rangle_V\;\;\;\text{for }u,v\in V_0\;.$$ We can show (see [Röckner, Proposition 2.5.2](https://books.google.de/books?id=Q-JDooJbjCAC&pg=PA39&lpg=PA39&dq=%22Then+the+process+given+by+the+following+proposition+is+called+a+cylindrical%22&source=bl&ots=QOm7DY-VZH&sig=y4zygMVRPIryVszDiDMT5R6R3hg&hl=de&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjZ9vO5047NAhVI3SwKHXTwB7cQ6AEIHTAA#v=onepage&q=%22Then%20the%20process%20given%20by%20the%20following%20proposition%20is%20called%20a%20cylindrical%22&f=false)) that $\iota$ is an isometry between $U_0$ and $$V_0=\iota U_0\;.\tag 2$$

However, I think I've found a special case which let me doubt on $(1)$ and $(2)$.

> Choose $Q=\text{id}_U$ and $V$ such that $U_0\subseteq V$ with the inclusion $\iota$ being Hilbert-Schmidt. Then, $$V_0\stackrel{(2)}=U_0=U\tag 3$$ and $$C=\text{id}_V\tag 4$$ (compare with [my other question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1812079/can-we-find-a-concrete-representation-of-iota-iota-ast-y-if-iota-is-a-hi)).

The problem is that $(4)$ yields $C^{1/2}=\text{id}_V$ and hence $$V_0=V\tag 5$$ by $(1)$. In particular, $$V=V_0=U_0=U\;.\tag 6$$

> So, either I made some mistake or the only way to choose a superspace $V$ of $U_0$ such that the inclusion $\iota$ is Hilbert-Schmidt is the trivial choice $U_0=V$.

---

$\mathfrak L(A,B)$ and $\operatorname{HS}(A,B)$ denote the space of bounded, linear operators and [Hilbert-Schmidt operators](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hilbert%E2%80%93Schmidt_operator) from $A$ to $B$, respectively.

Comment: finite rank operators have finite trace

Comment: @user1952009 While that's true, I don't know what you want to tell me.